# Converting .aiff audio file to .wav

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to convert some audio files using a python script. The source folder contains both `.wav` and `.aiff` audio files, with different bitrates and sampling rates.

**INPUT Files example**

[image]

I need all the audio files to be converted to *mono 16bit 44.1khz* .wav

**OUTPUT Files example**

[image]

At the moment I'm succesfully using [pysoundfile](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.1/) library to open and write/convert `.wav` files to `PCM_16` type.

What I don't know how to do, is converting `.aiff` files to `.wav` ones.

I know Python handles `.aiff` files with the `aifc` library, but it doesn't seems to include any kind of conversion functionality.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** Probably this is not the answer you're looking for, because it is not "Python-only"; however, when I tried to work with media files in a large Python script I found this method easier than searching and reading documentation of a bunch of libraries for each media format I needed.

Install a media converter (f.e., I use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)), whose commands you can execute from Windows command line or Linux terminal. Then you can call these commands from a Python script:

```
from subprocess import call 
call('ffmpeg -i D:/Audio/IN/sample.aiff -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 D:/Audio/OUT/sample.wav')
```

(Here '-ac 1' means 1 audio track, that is, we convert to mono.) You can also extract audio from any video format in a similar way.

Comment: I tried ffmpeg and It seems like only extension is changed and it is not playable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-issue. The `soundfile` module you are already using does support AIFF files out-of-the-box. Just specify the file name and you are done!

You can use the function [soundfile.available_formats()](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#soundfile.available_formats) to get a list of supported formats.
The `soundfile` module uses the `libsndfile` library under the hood. There is a [list of supported formats](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/#Features) on their homepage (which contains AIFF).

Like @Wolfram mentioned, you can of course also use FFmpeg instead.
Another great external tool for audio conversion is [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: True, `soundfile` module supports AIFF files but it doesn't seems to offer any .wav to .aiff conversion method. I think I'll be better do everything with SoX anyway

Comment: It indeed doesn't offer a function to do the conversion in a single step. However, it is very simple to open a file for reading and write all its audio content into a new file with a different format. But if you only want to convert from one format to another, an external tool probably makes more sense.